# Source Operators Stuck in the requestBufferBuilderBlocking

Tags: apache-flink

I keep seeing the following situation where a task is blocked getting a MemorySegment from the pool but the operator is still reporting.

I'm completely stumped as to how to debug or what to look at next so any hints/help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

The situation is as follows (Flink 1.12.2):

[pool usage of the operator and its downstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAiWK.png)

As you can see from 02:00 to 08:00, no records is produced from this purchase source while there still a bunch of records need to be processed from Kafka. And during this period of time. The outPoolUsage is around 0.6 and the downstream operators seems also have the available buffer. We redeployed the job and disabled unaligned checkpoint at around 9 so it becomes normal now.

The thread dump we took shows that we are stuck here:

```
"Legacy Source Thread - Source: Kafka Reader - ACCOUNT - kafka-bootstrap-url.com:9443 (1/5)#2" #9250 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5
9490.62ms elapsed=8399.28s tid=0x00007f0e99c23910 nid=0x2df5 waiting on condition [0x00007f0fa85fe000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
 at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
 - parking to wait for <0x00000000ab5527c8> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.8/LockSupport.java:194)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:1796)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@11.0.8/ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:1823)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:1998)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestMemorySegmentBlocking(LocalBufferPool.java:319)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBufferBuilderBlocking(LocalBufferPool.java:291)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.requestNewBufferBuilderFromPool(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:337)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.requestNewUnicastBufferBuilder(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:313)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.appendUnicastDataForRecordContinuation(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:257)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.emitRecord(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:149)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:104)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.ChannelSelectorRecordWriter.emit(ChannelSelectorRecordWriter.java:54)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:101)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:87)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:43)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:322)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:426)
 - locked <0x00000000aef80e00> (a java.lang.Object)
```